# Why do electrons not flow through the electrolyte?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, electrons, electricity

Why do the electrons not flow through the electrolyte instead of the external circuit in a electrolytic cell connected to an external circuit? I mean, if an electrolyte is a conductor why would the electrons take the way through the external circuit rather than through the electrolyte to the other electrode of an opposite charge?

Like:

[image]

Comment: Ah, thanks @Mithoron. Thought for sure I'd seen a dupe of this before.

Comment: Oh I accepted the duplicate vote by mistake haha... Anyway, I do not see how it answers it. So think I need a little further help :)

Comment: asd, the short answer is that electrons ***can't*** carry current within the electrolyte, because they are too reactive: they would immediately react to form ions. The electrolyte is a conductor because it's an *ionic* conductor.